# Find quoted strings with only lower case letters?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2005

In visual studio 2005 I try to find all strings with the "Find in Files" dialog that contains only lower case letters, using the following regexp:

```
\"[a-z\.]+\"
```

But I get both lower and upper case quoted strings. Is the regexp wrong in someway ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `"[a-z]+"` would normally only match lower case letters. Visual Studio's Find regex syntax is a bit different though - you need to check the 'Match Case' option, else it'll always do case insensitive matching.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't use modifiers, use the "Match Case" option.

Also `.` doesn't work in character classes (i.e. `[...]`). It's seen as a regular dot.

Answer (score 0):

`.` means "any character other than `\n`".